# How to show a popup on click of a radio button in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a ReactJs project where I am have a 2 radio button.One radio button will have a value of email id and the other will have a value of 'No Email Alerts'.Also, there is a save button on the page. So, when I click the 'No Email Alerts' radio button and click on the save button, I have to get a popup which says, **"You will stop getting email alerts.Do you want to continue?"**.So, to check which radio button is clicked and to show the popup, I added 2 state values My code structure looks like this.

```
 this.state = {
          noAlertPopUpClicked:false,
          showNoAlertPopup:false
}
```

Then in my `onRadioClick()` function I have added a condition as:

```
 onRadioClick = (e, keys) => {
        if(e.target.value === 'No text message alerts'){
            this.setState({noAlertPopUpClicked: !this.state.noAlertPopUpClicked});
        }
}
```

I have another function `confirmNoAlertClicked()` which will show the popUp:

```
confirmNoAlertClicked() {
    alert(this.state.noAlertPopUpClicked);
    if(this.state.noAlertPopUpClicked) {
      this.setState({showNoAlertPopup : true});
    }
  }
```

Then in my render function,

```
        <DialogBox
          displayDialog={this.state.showNoAlertPopup} >
           <ConfirmEmail /> 
        </DialogBox>
```

The `<DialogBox />` component is already defined which opens a popup based on the prop `displayDialog`.The `<ConfirmEmail />` component is the content of the DialogBox. Now, the issue I am facing is, when I click on the no alerts radio button and then click save, for the first time, the dialog box shows up, but if I click the save button again, the dialog box doesn't show up. Is my state not updating properly. Can anyone please guide me?

**Edit 1:** My save button is:

```
             <SceButton
              id='Save'
              buttonType='sceDisabled'
              value='Save' 
              onClick={this.confirmNoAlertClicked} />
```

Comment: Where is confirmNoAlertClicked() invoked?

Comment: @Alpe89 It's invoked on the save button click.Sorry i forgot to add the code earlier, I have added it now in an edit.Can you please check.

Comment: In the DialogBox component is there something that checks the value of this.state.showNoAlertPopup? I ask you this because, from what I see in your code, that property never goes back to false.

Comment: @Alpe89 You are correct, I tried adding passing a new function which will set the value of the showNoAlertPopup to false and now the popup shows up as expected, but 1 issue is I am able to see the popup even when the the other radio button is clicked, why is this happening?

Comment: @Alpe89 its solved. I had to add an else condition inside the onRadioClick which sets the noAlertPopUpClicked to false. Anyways thanks a lot for your help. :)

Comment: I'm glad to have been helpful